# Stationarity in quarterly overlapping data

Tags: autocorrelation, stationarity, overlapping-data

If I have a time series of quarterly default rates (e.g. of mortgages), by definition they will be 75% correlated, thus leading in non stationarity.

What should I do in this case? Can I ignore lags up to 4 due to the structure of the data? Or should I handle it differently due to the fact that they are non stationary?

Comment: Nonzero autocorrelation does not imply nonstationarity. Consider AR(1) process with slope coefficient $-1<\varphi_1<1$; the process is autocorrelated but nevertheless stationary.

Comment: What if my results show non stationarity? Can I say I will look at lags higher than 4 due to the fact that the default rates might be overlapping? Or I have to look at the first four lags as well? That is my question.

Comment: Nonstationarity is not likely to be impacted by overlapping observations. Whether they overlap or not (as you remove every 3 out of 4 observations), the status of stationarity will likely remain the same.

Comment: I do not remove any observations. A loan might appear to be defaulted (or not defaulted) in Q1 and in Q2, Q3, Q4 etc, even for many years. Should I look at lags only higher than 4 or should I also look at the first four lags for stationarity?

Comment: See my previous comment. Otherwise, why do you want to look at lags if you care about stationarity?

Comment: Do I need to look only at the first lag for stationarity? Or for more than 1 lags?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do? Otherwise it is unclear why you are focusing on lags when your main concern is stationarity.

Comment: I am trying to see whether the time series is stationary or not. Shouldn't I be looking for the lags to answer this question?

Comment: Should you? What method are you implementing? What about running some test, e.g. augmented Dickey-Fuller; Phillips-Perron; Elliott, Rothenberg & Stock?

Comment: Yes, augmented Dickey Fuller (ADF) and Phillips Perron